# How to execute document.querySelectorAll on a text string without inserting it into DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var html = '<p>sup</p>'
```

I want to run `document.querySelectorAll('p')` on that text without inserting it into the dom.

In jQuery you can do `$(html).find('p')`

If it's not possible, what's the cleanest way to to do a temporary insert making sure it doesn't interfere with anything. then only query that element. then remove it.

(I'm doing ajax requests and trying to parse the returned html)

Comment: [Use a document fragment.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

With IE 10 and above, you can use the **[DOM Parser object](http://devdocs.io/dom/domparser)** to parse DOM directly from HTML.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
var paragraphs = doc.querySelectorAll('p');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create temporary element, append html to it and run querySelectorAll

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>sup</p>');
element.querySelectorAll('p')
```

Comment: Or you can also do: `element.innerHTML = '<p>sup</p>';`

Comment: Yes you can but consider this jsperf http://jsperf.com/insertadjacenthtml/14 Example html is trivial but I assume  real usage will be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

with Node.Js this is my workable pattern

```
 const html = (strings, ...values) => String.raw({ raw: strings }, ...values);
 const doc = html`<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en-US">
     <head>
       <title>Hello</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div id="1">a</div>
       <div id="2">b</div>
     </body>
   </html>`;

 const jsdom = require("jsdom");   
 const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(doc);

 const Divs = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("div");

 for (const one of Divs) {
     console.log(one.outerHTML)
 }
```

result is

```
<div id="1">a</div>
<div id="2">b</div>
```