# how do i get DOM (element via class name) from a xmlhttp / "text/html"

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

```
function getSourceAsDOM(url) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  parser=new DOMParser();
  return parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText,"text/html");      
}
```

I use this function to get the html of a web page via link.

I want to search it for a specific div. how do i do it?

I tried `element.querySelectorAll('.nameOfClass')` but i get NodeList[] with 0 elements.

if I console.log() it i get #document

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040319/how-to-execute-document-queryselectorall-on-a-text-string-without-inserting-it-i

Comment: FYI: making a synchronous requests is not the best thing to do.

Comment: `getSourceAsDOM('yoururl'`).querySelectorAll('.nameOfClass')` does not return anything?

Comment: If the MIME type returned by the server is "text/html", `xmlhttp.response` is a `Document`. It requires the use of asynchronous HTTP and setting the `responseType` correctly. See [HTML in XMLHttpRequest at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest)